# How to execute a ClientHttpRequestInterceptor last in RestTemplate (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have multiple ClientHttpRequestInterceptor set up as my common configuration for my RestTemplate (CommonRestTemplateBuilder), one of which is a LogRequestInterceptor.

The problem is when I add a new ClientHttpRequestInterceptor in a new @Configuration in which I create another RestTemplate using as a base the commonRestTemplateBuilder, the interceptor for logging is executed before the new interceptor.

The problem here is that the new interceptor adds headers which are not reflected in the log.

Is it possible to give the interceptors an order?

This is the code:

```
/**
 * Configures the common rest template builder for building {@link RestTemplate}
 */
@Bean
public RestTemplateBuilder commonRestTemplateBuilder(HttpClient httpClient) {

    return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .requestFactory(() -> {
                //Use Apache Http Client request factory
                HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
                //Use the apache caching http client
                requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
                //Use buffering client for debugging (get the body of the request)
                return new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory);
            })
            .customizers()
            .interceptors(
                    //For adding common headers
                    new AddCommonsHeadersRequestInterceptor(),
                    //For logging the requests
                    new LogRequestInterceptor());
}
```

Then in another class:

```
/**
 * Configures the {@link RestTemplate} for {@link CompanyAClient}
 * using as a base the {@link CommonRestTemplateConfiguration}.
 */
@Bean
public RestTemplate companyARestTemplate() {

    return commonRestTemplateBuilder
            .rootUri("http://companyA.com/api")
            .additionalInterceptors(new AddCompanyAHeadersRequestInterceptor())
            .build();
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible. From Spring 5, interceptors are sorted using [AnnotationAwareOrderComparator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.html). From your side, you'll simply put annotation @Order or @Priority on your interceptors:

```
@Order(1)
public class FirstInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
...
}

@Order(2)
public class SecondInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
...
}
```